# how to create and call extension function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val comingvalue = "\"6340040278031835\"".replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(), "");
    print(getAuthDigits(comingvalue))
}

fun getAuthDigits( number :String?): String? {
    return if (number?.length ?: 0 < 14) {
        null
    } else {
        number?.substring(10, 14)
    }
}
```

This is the function I am calling in the `main` method. Can anyone please suggest how to create an extension function and how to call it `main` method with a `comingvalue` input parameter?

Comment: What the class you need to be extended? please refer to this at first https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

do you mean the extension function is for the `comingvalue. getAuthDigits` ?

Comment: @AgiMaulana  getAuthDigits i have to make an extension function

Comment: fun String.getAuth(number:String?):String?{
   return if (number?.length ?: 0 < 14) {
            null
        } else {
            number?.substring(10, 14)
        }
}.  i  tried like this but i  am unable to call

Comment: I've posted the code you can try

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but what are you trying to do with `replace()`? In your example code, it will never replace anything because the string starts with `"`, not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun String.getAuthDigits(): String? {
    return if (this.length ?: 0 < 14) {
        null
    } else {
        this.substring(10, 14)
    }
}
```

and call this like below

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val comingvalue = "\"6340040278031835\"".replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(), "");
    print(comingvalue.getAuthDigits())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only place you call that function, you may as well write it inline.

You can use [`takeIf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) to return `null` if the condition is not satisfied:

```
fun main() {
    val authDigits: String? = """"6340040278031835""""
        .takeIf { it.length >= 14 }?.substring(10, 14)

    println(authDigits)
}
```

Output:

```
8031
```